# Transfer from terminal B to terminal C inside the Newark Airport

Tags: usa, transit, ewr

I will go to the Newark Liberty International Airport arrival terminal B (port of entry) from Hong Kong and then take a connected flight at terminal C to Boston Logan Airport after 4 hours. I'd like to verify whether the followings are correct or not?

1. I do not need to go out the secure zone in Newark Airport during the above whole process to Bonston, including the port of entry immigration, baggage claim, customs, bag drop to Boston flight during transfer and take the flight at terminal C to Boston.
2. After the above customs, where can I find the bag drop area for my baggage for the flight to Boston? Is there any sign or indication to show the Boston flight number over there to remind me to drop the bag inside the belt?
3. After the bag drop, I will take the shuttle bus from terminal B to terminal C and the shuttle bus should be still inside the secure zone.

Would you please try to verify the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The airside shuttle bus that United provides is only available to domestic transfers. International arrivals go out landside after customs and must go through security to take a connecting flight.

Here is what will happen when you arrive at Newark:

You will first go to US immigration, use a kiosk or have an interview, then go to baggage claim and pick up your checked bags. You then take these to customs where you either get your baggage inspected or get passed through.

The bag drop is right after you pass customs. It shouldn't be hard to find, as everyone else will be dropping their bags there too.

After you drop your bags, you'll be landside in Terminal B. You'll have to take the AirTrain to Terminal C, then go through TSA security, and finally to your departure gate.

Comment: Thanks, since all my flights are UA including the collecting flight to Boston, can I take their shuttle bus inside the secure zone from terminal B to terminal C without TSA check again in Newark Airport?

Comment: @James No, you have to go through security again. All international arrivals do for connecting flights after going through immigration/customs. When you exit customs you will be landside at the roadway and will need to go upstairs to departures.